# Module map not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, tttattributedlabel

I have installed pod File, but in issue this frame work. Any solution?

> Error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support
>   Files/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.modulemap': Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
>   “TTTAttributedLabel.modulemap”

Comment: could you provide pod file@user7236553

Comment: Sorry sir  pod file not share i

Comment: Ok no issue@user7236553